# Are subtitles available in Dragon Age Origins?

Tags: dragon-age-origins

While I possess a wonderful pair of speakers, I find that with their period accent, some of the NPCs in Dragon Age are woefully misunderstood (by me). I know that there are *some* captions in this game already, as the last line of dialog will appear at the top of the screen if you wait long enough when presented with dialog options, but I'm wondering if there is a setting somewhere that subtitles *all* spoken dialog.

I've looked under the in-game menu, and can't seem to find an option for it. Am I looking in the wrong place, or simply looking fruitlessly?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's directly on the game tab of the options dialog, for some ineffable reason in the Feedback area.

[image]

Comment: Excellent! Fie on misleading menus!

Answer (score 0):

I only have the 360 version but it should be similar:

On the start screen go to Options -> Audio/Video -> Subtitles

Comment: This is unfortunately not true for the PC version, which I have.